# "Hardclip" a TIN

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d

How do you go about hardclipping a TIN in Arc10? Previously there was a modify TIN tool, but I cannot seem to find it. So my question remains, how do I go about clipping a TIN with a polygon layer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit TIN. Arc Toolbox -> 3D Analyst Tools -> TIN Management -> Edit TIN
Add in the polygon Feature class and choose  for height field and hardclip for SF_Type

Comment: I had been performing the above operation to clip my TIN and wasn't appearing to get any results. I found the forum post by @Jakub as linked in the answer by @SaultDon and once I restarted ArcMap the TIN drew correctly (I didn't have to rerun the tool). Thanks for the post.

Comment: Just to clarify, "and choose for height field", should be "and choose none for height field".

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Edit Tin](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000048000000.htm) tool and if that doesn't work,

try to use the [clip](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000004000000.htm) tool to get your hardclip after your TIN has been converted to a polygon.

Here is a [forum topic](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/15239-Edit-TIN-%28Previously-Add-Features-to-TIN%29-Hardclip-Softclip-NOT-CLIPPING!) from the ESRI forums on an issue with this tool, so inspect your results.

Comment: No, because the clip tool only works with features, not surfaces. The TIN is not an option to apply the clip to in the drop-down menu.

Comment: Andrew, looks like I was editing while you responded, too fast for me, see if my revision now answers what you were looking for.